# How to save typed values inside the initialValues of Formik data?

Tags: reactjs, formik

I use Formik to create the form :

```
const initialValues = {
        groupName: '',
        description: '',
        testGroup: 0
    };

return (
        
        <Formik initialValues={initialValues} >
            
            {(formik) => {
                
                const { setValues } = formik;
                
                const onRadioGroupetestChange = (input) => {
                    setValues({
                        ...initialValues,
                        testGroup: Number(input)
                    });
                };
                
                return (
                    
                    <Form>
                        
                        <FormikControl
                            control="input"
                            label={_getText("group.name")}
                            name="groupName"
                            placeholder={_getText("placeholder.group.name")}
                        />

                        <FormikControl
                            control="textarea"
                            label={_getText("description")}
                            name="description"
                            placeholder={_getText("placeholder.group.descr")}
                        />

                        <FormikControl
                            formik={formik}
                            control="radio"
                            onChange={onRadioGroupetestChange}
                            initialValue={initialValues.testGroup}
                            name="testGroup"
                            label={_getText('group.test')}
                            options={radioDataGroupTest}
                        />

                        <Flex
                            flexWidth={1}
                            alignItems="center"
                            justifyContent="center"
                            margin="2rem 0 0 0"
                        >
                            <Flex margin="0 0.8rem 0 0">
                                <Button
                                    variant="line"
                                    text="Cancel"
                                    type="reset"
                                    onClick={closeModal}
                                />
                            </Flex>
                            <Flex margin="0 0 0 0.8rem">
                                <Button text="Submit" type="submit" />
                            </Flex>
                        </Flex>
                    </Form>
                );
            }}
        </Formik>
```

The FormikControl component with props "testGroup" renders two radio buttons.

At runtime when I click the unchecked button of the radio button then all the fields of the form are cleared. So how to save the data I entered in the components groupName and description ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's why you are resetting form with:

```js
setValues({
   ...initialValues,
   testGroup: Number(input)
});
```

Try [setFieldValue](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setfieldvalue-field-string-value-any-shouldvalidate-boolean--void) instead, or use [values](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#values--field-string-any-) instead of `initialFormValues`.